# Pass variable to certain parameter function and ignore the other

Tags: function, go, variables, parameters

I have this sample code

```
func myFunction(x string, y string) {
  fmt.Printf("Parameter X : %s",x) 
  fmt.Println("")
  fmt.Printf("Parameter Y : %s",y)
}
```

I want to pass my variable but only for parameter Y without parameter X, i don't know is there any way to do that ?

can someone give me some keyword reference for me too google it up

Thanks

=====

UPDATE

wow thanks now i've got several option

case closed

Comment: What value do you want the ignored parameter `X` to have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

But if you change your function to take a struct you can use named fields in the struct:

```
type xy struct{ x, y string }

func myFunction(v xy) {
    fmt.Printf("Parameter X : %v", v.x)
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Printf("Parameter Y : %v", v.y)
}

myFunction(xy{x: "1"})
```

Comment: With this solution, you can't tell the different between a specified value of `0` and being unset. You could do it by changing the `x` and `y` fields to pointers.

Comment: @Marc OP has not said they want to tell the difference between unset and "zero". I think it is only worth introducing pointers if that is a requirement.

Comment: I partially agree, except the difference between `func(0, 5)` and `func(5)` isn't really worth any special handling until you have a lot of parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make your constructor-like functions less rigid you can use functional options pattern. You can achieve your purpose with something like that:

```
// Client may be used to issue requests to special API
type Client struct {
    httpClient *http.Client
    apiKey     string
    baseURL    string
}

// ClientOption is the type of constructor options for NewClient(...).
type ClientOption func(*Client) error

// WithBaseURL configures an API client with a custom base url
func WithBaseURL(baseURL string) ClientOption {
    return func(c *Client) error {
        if baseURL == "" {
            return errors.New("lib: empty base url was provided")
        }
        c.baseURL = baseURL
        return nil
    }
}

// WithCustomClient configures an API client with a custom http.Client
func WithCustomClient(httpClient *http.Client) ClientOption {
    return func(c *Client) error {
        if httpClient == nil {
            return errors.New("lib: nil http client was provided")
        }
        c.httpClient = httpClient
        return nil
    }
}

// NewClient constructs a new Client which can make requests to
// WebService APIs.
func NewClient(apiKey string, options ...ClientOption) (*Client, error) {

    if apiKey == "" {
        return nil, errors.New("lib: API key credential missing")
    }

    c := &Client{apiKey: apiKey}
    _ = WithCustomClient(&http.Client{Timeout: 5 * time.Second})(c)
    for _, option := range options {
        err := option(c)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    return c, nil
}
```

Then you can use it in any way you want:

```
c, err := NewClient("key", WithCustomClient(httpClient)
// or
c, err := NewClient("key", WithCustomClient(httpClient), WithBaseURL(server.URL)
```

An example was adopted from production google maps go library for you to catch the idea. You can get more info about this pattern [here](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#functional-options)

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

Go doesn't have named parameters so the order of the parameters has to be fixed, no way to know which parameter is which otherwise.

What you could do instead is change your parameter types to pointers and pass nil for parameters you want to exclude. eg:

```
func myfunc(x *string, y *string) {
  if x != nil {
     fmt.Printf("Parameter X: %s\n",*x)
  }
  if y != nil { 
     fmt.Printf("Parameter Y: %s\n",*y)
  }
}
```

You can then call `y := "foo"; myfunc(nil, &y)`

Some other alternatives:

- change the parameters to be a map of `parameter name -> parameter value`, though at this point you're just making your life more complicated.
- pass a struct instead: `struct{x *int, y *int}` and either set the fields or leave them nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. But you can use Variadic functions if it serve your problem.

Variadic functions can be called with any number of trailing arguments

```
func myFunction(parameters ...int) {
  for i, parameter := range parameters {
       fmt.Printf("Parameter %d : %d\n",i ,parameter)
  }
}
```

And call like this using an arbitrary number of ints as arguments

```
myFunction(1)
myFunction(1,2)
```

Find details about Variadic functions [here](https://gobyexample.com/variadic-functions)

Comment: That's another option but I don't think that answers the question since it can't tell `x` and `y` apart.

Comment: Yes, but can use  index ordering after creating slice  for argument ordering like p[0] for X  and p[1] for Y.

Comment: The question is about leaving empty parameters. If my function can take up to 2 integers, this can't tell which of the two the parameter applies to.

Comment: @Marc there is a useful [Functional Options](https://medium.com/@dreissenzahn/functional-options-in-go-35279f535c6) pattern which uses variadic function in a way that you can tell the arguments apart but its almost certainly overkill in this case: https://play.golang.org/p/JNq0k1o8bKt . But it has a nice property that you can pass no arguments at all: `myFunction()`

Comment: I do like this pattern, but it still leaves you unable to distinguish between an intentional vs a default zero value. I might have read too much into OP's example, but there are cases where `x=0` is very different from `x is not set`. Again, the way to handle this with functional options is by changing everything to pointers.

Comment: @Marc clearly the Functional Option pattern can be modified to tell the difference between unset and "zero" without changing the API but I would only do so if that is a requirement.